# restrict special characters into input box

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

Am new on Angular.Need to restrict special characters into input box with angularjs

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cntry" ng-model="address.countryCode">
```

Allow only alphabets or digits

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Comment: What you trying to say is confusing, but if its HTML concern then you try this it may help to only accept alphabets of capital or small letter. Just add this pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" --- <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" class="form-control" id="cntry" ng-model="address.countryCode" >

Comment: Check https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern  & https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Answer (score 0):

Define a regex in your controller

```
$scope.regex = /^[^`~!@#$%\^&*()_+={}|[\]\\:';"<>?,./1-9]*$/;
```

And in your html use a `ng-pattern` directives and pass the above regex as pattern.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cntry"
       ng-model="address.countryCode" ng-pattern="regex">
```

For more info visit [Restrict Special Characters in HTML & AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005810/restrict-special-characters-in-html-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution by adding pattern:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cntry"
       ng-model="address.countryCode" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$}">
```