# Is there anyway to skip the particular character by regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I have the input field as Text in HTML5 and I want to reject these characters , ; : |  by using Regex pattern.

And I finally found the regex pattern but the other language is not accepting in that input field. Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

I tired this one.

`oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9'\@#$.A-Za-z!%^&*(){}_ -]+/g, '')">`

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-sm"  ng-model="department.name"
                                   ng-required="true" ng-change="resetError()" ng-maxlength="25"
                                   show-focus="deptFormStatus" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9'\@#$.A-Za-z!%^&*(){}_ -]+/g, '')">
```

Comment: What do you mean with `but the other language is not accepting in that input field`?

Comment: Since you're using angularjs, don't mix it with regular javascript but do this in angular way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict Special Characters in HTML & AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005810/restrict-special-characters-in-html-angularjs)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ? Are you trying to remove special character from input or only `, ; : |` ?

Comment: special character should not allow in input type